# Нужна ли запятая в предложении с «то ли... то ли...»

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, союзы, однородные-члены

Скажите, пожалуйста, нужна ли вторая запятая? И почему.

*То ли от нахлынувших эмоций, то ли от витающих в воздухе запахов(,) у него потекли слёзы.*

Comment: нужна тире, обобщение. То ли от нахлынувших эмоций, то ли от витающих в воздухе запахов - (от всего этого) у него потекли слёзы. И тут не то ли, а то ли от

Comment: Это(случилось) ли от нахлынувших эмоций... То - это подлежащие и не союз, а если рассуждать, что это союз, то не нужна. Если "у него потекли слезы" - вывод, то нужна тире, а если это констатация факта, то ничего не нужно. Но как констатация факта звучит немного странно, например, на вопрос: а чего он плачет? -Да не знаю. То ли от нахлынувших эмоций, то ли от витающий в воздухе запахов у него потекли слезы. Он же аллергик, но иногда любит и поистерить.

Comment: @Буратино Интересно, как "то" здесь могут быть подлежащими? Интонационное тире допустимо, но оно более вероятно в такой структуре: *У него потекли слёзы – то ли от нахлынувших эмоций, то ли от витающих в воздухе запахов.*

Comment: @АлександрСтрелец не знаю, может из-за того что точная причина не указана, то есть этот ряд можно было бы и продолжить, но в месте знака препинания интонационная тире. Без тире не то ощущение совсем, без тире нет интонации сомнения. Может это моё субъективное прочтение. Но я бы в таком предложении поставил тире, так как точной причины не указано, а значит присутствует неуверенность и наблюдение - у него потекли слезы, а если неуверенности нет, нафиг такая конструкция нужна. То ли то... - это мысли автора, а потекли слезы - это то что он видит.

Comment: @АлександрСтрелец может потому что причина определяет как вообще понимать его слезы, это слезы от эмоций или это слезы как реакция организма на пыльцу или запах. То есть вообще не понятно, это эмоция и слезы или это просто влага течет из глаз, слезы это или нет. Вообще не понятно) Но как факт вот слезы текут, почему - не ясно вообще, слезы это или нет, тоже не ясно. То есть левая часть и правая не связаны причинностью. Это место разрывает предложение на куски. То ли от нахлынувших эмоций, то ли от витающих в воздухе запахов, (но) у него потекли слёзы - может так?

Comment: Во всех ваших примерах значение правой части не меняется от выбора причины, ну или оно не важно. А тут оно определяет что происходит. И это не как у Никулина "кривились ноги" - то есть происходило что-то странное, неописуемое, а причины не существенны. Тут происходит: либо слезы, либо вода из глаз - что течет? Причины очень даже существенны и определяют. Или нет. Не ясно.

Comment: @Буратино Вас трудно понять... "влага", "вода" из глаз...  Ну да ладно, проехали...

Comment: @АлександрСтрелец хорошо), вот в такой форме это предложение тоже самое или нет? То ли от нахлынувших эмоций, то ли от витающих в воздухе запахов, но у него потекли слёзы.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Необходимости в запятой нет.

***То ли... то ли...*** – это повторяющийся союз, соединяющий в данном случае однородные члены предложения (см. [Справочник под ред. Лопатина](http://orthographia.ru/punctum_uk.php?pid=632)).

Если убрать союз, ситуация станет более очевидной:
*От нахлынувших эмоций, от витающих в воздухе запахов у него потекли слёзы.*

**Аналогичные примеры** из [Национального корпуса русского языка](https://ruscorpora.ru/results?search=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):

*То ли от нервов, то ли от промозглой погоды его легко знобило...* [Николай Дежнев. Принцип неопределенности (2009)]

*То ли от этого страшного свиста, то ли от сквозняка из открытой форточки у Петьки по голому телу бежали мурашки.* [Андрей Геласимов. Степные боги (2008)]

*То ли из-за спешки, то ли от волнения все летело у меня из рук...* [Вера Белоусова. Второй выстрел (2000)]

*То ли от этих интенсивных аэротанцев, то ли из-за некачественной записи звук вдруг исчез напрочь, а изображение начало рябить.* [Александр Зильберт. Укрепление тонуса (1997)]

*И у нее то ли от волнения, то ли еще по какой причине вдруг странно начинают кривиться ноги.* [Юрий Никулин. Мое любимое кино (1979)]

*То ли от водки, то ли от нагретых ног жилка утихла, звон кончился...*  [O. М. Куваев. Кто-то должен курлыкать (1975)]

*То ли от солнца, то ли от завтрака, то ли от того и другого вместе у Чонкина улучшилось настроение и прошло ощущение близкой опасности.* [Владимир Войнович. Жизнь и необычайные приключения солдата Ивана Чонкина (1969-1975)]

*Поднялась паника, но то ли от пресной воды, то ли от канберрской скуки акула издохла.* [Д. А. Гранин. Месяц вверх ногами (1966)]